# Stuck with mysql join with count query

Tags: mysql, join, count

I'm having a problem with joining 2 queries but in the second query I only want to bring in the count.

This first query works well

```
SELECT DISTINCT forum_sub.sub_id, forum_id, title, text, url, forum_sub.userid, members.first_name, views 
FROM forum_sub, members 
WHERE members.userid = forum_sub.userid AND forum_sub.forum_id = 1 
ORDER BY forum_sub.timestamp DESC
```

which displays the following

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
sub_id | forum_id | title | text | url | userid | first_name | views |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  20   |    1     | test  | test |test | 1001   | JOhn       | 123   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   |    1     | test  | test |test | 1002   | Pete       |  23   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  10   |    1     | test  | test |test | 1003   | Harry      |  34   |                                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But now I want to join the above sub_id to another table called forum_topics and count how many of the same sub_id's there are and bring in that value

for example I could use

SELECT sub_id, COUNT(sub_id) as topics FROM forum_topics GROUP BY sub_id

```
-----------------
|sub_id | topics|
  ---------------
|   1   |   4   |
-----------------
|   10  |   3   |
-----------------
|   20  |   5   |
-----------------
```

My question is how can I join those 2 queries so I get something like this

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub_id | forum_id | title | text | url | userid | first_name | views | count|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  20   |    1     | test  | test |test | 1001   | JOhn       | 123   |  5   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1   |    1     | test  | test |test | 1002   | Pete       |  23   |  4   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  10   |    1     | test  | test |test | 1003   | Harry      |  34   |  3  |                                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be great, I know I need to use a subquery but I've been stuck on this nearly all day with no luck

Comment: What are you using forum topic for? The `where` clause might require some changes based on your `from` clause.

Comment: forum_topics shouldn't really been needed in the top query, but forum_topics is the table where the count of the sub_id is, for example there could 10 comments for that topic and I want it to count how many is in each of the topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First avoid SELECT DISTINCT when ever possible. It is evil.  It will hide cross joins etc that you have in your query.  From this query it is hard to tell what exactly your are doing.

However to include the count you have a couple of options:

One would be to do a sub select in the query:

```
SELECT forum_sub.sub_id, forum_id, title, text, url, forum_sub.userid, 
members.first_name, views , (SELECT COUNT(sub_id) as topics FROM forum_topics WHERE sub_id = forum_sub.sub_id) count
FROM forum_sub, members 
WHERE members.userid = forum_sub.userid AND forum_sub.forum_id = 1 
ORDER BY forum_sub.timestamp DESC
```

Another would be to actually join to the sub query you created:

```
SELECT forum_sub.sub_id, forum_id, title, text, url, forum_sub.userid, 
       members.first_name, views, counts.topics
FROM forum_sub, members 
JOIN (SELECT sub_id, COUNT(sub_id) as topics FROM forum_topics GROUP BY sub_id) counts     ON (counts.sub_id = forum_sub.sub_id)
WHERE members.userid = forum_sub.userid AND forum_sub.forum_id = 1 
ORDER BY forum_sub.timestamp DESC
```

You should also look at joins instead of selecting multiple tables in your from

```
SELECT forum_sub.sub_id, forum_id, title, text, url, forum_sub.userid, 
       members.first_name, views, counts.topics
FROM forum_sub
JOIN members ON (members.userid = forum_sub.userid)
JOIN (SELECT sub_id, COUNT(sub_id) as topics FROM forum_topics GROUP BY sub_id) counts ON (counts.sub_id = forum_sub.sub_id)
WHERE forum_sub.forum_id = 1 
ORDER BY forum_sub.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Wow you are a very smart dude, thank you thank you, great explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
group by sub_id
```

at the end of your second query instead of WHERE.
Then join it to the other table.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work, I've edited the code to make it more explainable